# Enumeration across many sections

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I am trying to combine enumeration over multiple sections: it is not working.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} 

\begin{center} 
\textbf{class X}
\end{center}

\item \hangindent=7mm \noindent \footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{AAAAA} \normalsize
\item \hangindent=7mm \noindent BBBBB

\begin{center} 
\textbf{class Y}
\end{center}

\item \hangindent=7mm \noindent \footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{CCCCC} \normalsize

\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

How do I achieve enumeration automatically for all items marked \item while not enumerating section titles placed in between them?

EDIT: the answer below results in the centered section heading actually being offcenter, to the right a bit. How do I completely center them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` and its `resume` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% to show the page grid. Remove!
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{center}
\textbf{class X}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{AAAAA} \normalsize
\item  BBBBB
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}
\textbf{class Y}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{CCCCC} \normalsize
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently we posted the very same approach at the same time. `:)` I'll delete mine in favour of yours. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Oho! I didn't see your answer Paulo (slow internet). But you are early by 2 minutes.

Comment: Nah don't worry. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you seek?  What I did was use `\hfil`s and `\hfill`s, instead of centering, and made the headers `\item`s without a label.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} 

\item[] \hfil\textbf{class X}\hspace{\the\leftmargin}\hfill


\item \hangindent=7mm \noindent \footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{AAAAA} \normalsize
\item \hangindent=7mm \noindent BBBBB

\item[] \hfil\textbf{class Y}\hspace{\the\leftmargin}\hfill

\item \hangindent=7mm \noindent \footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{CCCCC} \normalsize

\end{enumerate} 

\centering CENTERED

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDITED to achieve centering of enumerated headers.  An `\hspace` is added after the header and before the `\hfill`.  The amount (set to `\the\leftmargin`) corresponds to the indentation level of the environment.