# Negative indent?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, indentation, paragraphs

Is a negative indent of a particular paragraph possible or does another command need to be used? I.e., the first line should begin inside the margin.

Can a command similar to `\noindent` be constructed that flushes the first line (of a paragraph) to an arbitrary value, or does a negative indent already exist, or is there an easy-to-make solution?

Comment: You can simply use `\hspace*{-3cm}blablabalbabal`. Or set `\parindent` to a negative value.

Comment: This comment is actually what I was looking for, with \hspace*{-Xmm}! Please add this as an answer, so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply use `\hspace*{-3cm}blablabalbabal`.

Answer (score 11):

Just set `\parindent` to a negative value, e.g.

```
\setlength{\parindent}{-1em}
```

If you want to keep original `\parindent` for other paragraphs, make the change local, e.g.

```
\bgroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-1em} 
PARAGRAPH
\egroup
```

Answer (score 7):

We can set the `\parindent` parameter locally and force the beginning of a paragraph in the same group. The end of the group will restore the former value of `\parindent`, but the different value has already been used. Note that `\negpar` should not be followed by a blank line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\negpar}[1][-1em]{%
  \ifvmode\else\par\fi
  {\parindent=#1\leavevmode}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

Some text with normal indentation. And other text to fill the 
paragraph over a couple of lines or maybe three, just add 
nonsense text forever and ever and beyond for years.

\negpar
Some text with negative indentation. And other text to fill the 
paragraph over a couple of lines or maybe three, just add 
nonsense text forever and ever and beyond for years.

Some text with normal indentation. And other text to fill the 
paragraph over a couple of lines or maybe three, just add 
nonsense text forever and ever and beyond for years.

\negpar[-2em]
Some text with negative indentation. And other text to fill the 
paragraph over a couple of lines or maybe three, just add 
nonsense text forever and ever and beyond for years.

Some text with normal indentation. And other text to fill the 
paragraph over a couple of lines or maybe three, just add 
nonsense text forever and ever and beyond for years.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful to know. Here is what I've done with it and the \hspace solution below: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142197/enumeration-in-margins-and-hang-indentation/142241#142241 In this case the \hspace solution is shorter, but this is also something useful in general. Can we accept two answers :)